# How to integrate Google Sign-In in website?

Tags: javascript, html, server, google-signin

I want use the Google Sign-In integration for my website, and I followed [this doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in)
and [this code](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/)
.
Unfortunately, this doesn't work, a pop-up appears, log me in, but the informations I need by doing `console.log()` doesn't appear in the console. 
Here is my entire code:

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="myclientid.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"></div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        document.write('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        document.write("ID Token: " + id_token);
      }
    </script>

    <script>
    document.write('Hello !');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helping

**EDIT** This works on Edge, but not on Google Chrome.[image: this is the error I get]

**SOLVED** I deleted all the existing creditentials and I created new one. This worked.